# Merge bug fixes patches from release branch to master branch

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

I have one `master` branch where i am pushing my latest development.

Now at some point, I do release and create new branch called `release1` from master branch.

Now i am doing new development on `master` branch

Meantime other team also perform some bug fixes on `release1` branch.

Now time come for release2. Here i need to include bug fixes done on release1 to the updated master branch and then fork `release2` branch.

New `release2` branch should have all bug fixes done on release1 branch  + latest development occurs after release1 on master branch.

What are the different possible workflow here.And based on that how to play with `git merge` and `git rebase` and `git cherry-pick` command here?

Comment: Before you ask/start worrying about the actual Git commands, you first need to decide how you are going to handle this workflow.  So a bug fix has been made to only `release1`, but now you have a second release coming.  You could merge the first release branch back to master, and then rebase the second release branch.  Or, you could cherry pick the bug fix.  There are a number of ways to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Solution which I prefer is as below.

master -> release1

master will have its own further development,

suppose some bug in `release1` branch then one should create `hotfix` branch from `release1` branch and after fixing bug in `hotfix` branch, just merge it into `release1` branch and rebase `hotfix` with `master` branch to maintain history, once rebased with `master` branch merge `hotfix` in `master` branch so bug fixing will be in both `master` and `release1` branch

now suppose it's time to have `release2`, you just need to create `release2` branch from `master` branch because all the bugs are already fixed in master branch as well as all the new developments are in `master` branch.

```
Master
 commit1
 commit2 -> release1
 commit3
 commit4


git checkout release1
git checkout -b hotfix

Hotfix
 commit2
 bugfix1
```

Merge hotfix with release1 will become

```
git checkout release1
git merge hotfix

Release1
 Commit1
 commit2
 butfix1
```

Rebase hotfix with master it will rewrite your history

```
git checkout hotfix
git rebase master

Hotfix
 commit1
 commit2
 commit3
 commit4
 bugfix1
```

after that merge hotfix branch to master branch

```
git checkout master
git merge hotfix

Master
 commit1
 commit2
 commit3
 commit4
 bugfix1

git branch -d hotfix
git push -d origin hotfix
```

don't forgot to delete `hotfix` because we are already done with that branch there is no more requirement of that branch once merged. you can also change names of hotfix branch to the jira ticket id or bug id if logged somewhere.

now creating release2 from master which is already have bug fixed in it.

Comment: This helped clarify some concepts for me, so thank you for posting it.